# How do I get the Mac OS X 'quick look' feature to be more programmer-friendly?

Tags: macos, performance

There are numerous text files that are always included in common downloads such as rails plugins: LICENSE, ChangeLog, Rakefile, etc.

I *know* these files are plain-text, but Mac OS X refuses to acknowledge this automatically. If I hit the spacebar in Finder to activate "quick look", the icon becomes huge but the contents of the file are not shown, presumably because they have no file extension.

How do I stop this madness so I can *quickly* look at READMEs just by hitting the spacebar?

I've already got a ton of text editors installed on my mac: this question is purely about efficiency and making simple files accessible as quickly as possible.

Comment: Not programming related.  See http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071028184428583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how long it will take before people are happy to answer StackOverflow questions without calling the questioner's priorities into question.

Thanks Agos for the pointer to the syntax coloring plugins. After much surfing I found the exact QuickLook enhancement I was looking for:

http://whomwah.github.com/qlstephen/

Comment: It's impossible for us to know that your priority choices are perfect.  We offer alternatives because some people don't have perfect priorities and are pursuing non-solutions to poorly-thought-through problems.  Some people have perfect priorities -- but it's impossible to tell.  Please rephrase your answer to make it clearly usable by others, without the complaint.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install (or possibly develop from scratch) a suitable quick look plugin.
You can find tons of them on sites such as:

- [www.quicklookplugins.com](http://www.quicklookplugins.com/)
- [www.qlplugins.com](http://www.qlplugins.com/)

An excellent starting point is to get a syntax coloring plugin!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://code.google.com/p/qlcolorcode/

Does syntax highlighting for a lot of languages, and if it's a language it doesn't understand, it just displays.  Seems to work for me.